# How use the default Magento's 'saveAction'

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-controller

I want to change the `$product->save();` for the saveAction Magento use's when you push the button in the admin.

I don't know why, but with the first doesn't save it equal.

I need to don't go or be redirect to other site because i want to put it in a cron.

UPDATE

> I'm importing/updating products from a csv. The problem is two of them
>   isn't shown in the search (frontend) because one attribute fails (but
>   works in the others)

If you go to the admin - enter in the product - push 'save' or 'save & continue', it works as i expected.

My conclusion is `$product->save()`, and `saveAction` do different things

Comment: As mentioned on the post, in the admin product controller, _initProduct() gets a standard product object.  Then ->save() is called on that product in the saveAction method.

Comment: But i can't call _initProduct(), so, how can i repair the product?

Comment: I've updated my answer - but anyhow; I am saying that when you save through the front end - standard product is initialized in the _initProduct() method in the admin product controller.  The product is then saved in the saveAction method.   I am just saying that when you save in your script, and when Magento saves in admin - you're saving the same object type, with the same save method.  However, the data that Magento admin will populate on the product will be different to what you populate in your script.  So perhaps you're missing something in script and the admin save resets the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks BAF, You've gived me the clue.

What happends is that the attribute is saved in one of the stores (that is correct) but it isn't in the default attributes (store 0), so i solved it adding to the importer:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

if (!$product->getData('attr')) {
    $product->setData('attr', '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** 
Regarding last comment: Maybe compare the data you're sending for the products that aren't saving correctly with those which are showing on front end.  Also check if they have stock, they're set to 'in_stock', they have inventory, they're assigned to categories, they're visible on the front end and enabled.

**EDIT:**

The save in the admin uses the same object and method than what you're using most likely.  However, the data when saving in admin will fill in any gaps required to make the product complete.  However, in your script perhaps you've missed something/or there are some errors saving using the data you have - therefore although the product is saved, it's not able to be displayed.

When you click save in the admin it likely sets the data you've missed.  Please share any code/errors you might have.

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE:**

Not quite sure what you're after.  What does it mean 'first doesn't save it equal'?  And what are you intending to do in a cron?  Save a product, where will the data come from?

If you're talking about saving a product on the edit page, I think $product->save() used?  If you check \core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Catalog\ProductController.php a product is initialized via Mage::getModel('catalog\product') - _initProduct() and saved via ->save() in the saveAction() method.  So what do you want to do?

On a side note:

If you only want to update a product's attributes via mass action (select products from list and select 'update attributes' you can use \Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Action.php updateAttributes() action.  This will update multiple products and multiple attributes per store.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: Perhaps elaborate on the errors you're getting - because it looks to be like the same save method is being called.  If you're not seeing a product in the front end and saving the product in admin corrects it - then it's likely something to do with the data you're sending - and the admin save 'resets' the product with all required data.  Maybe share your update script.

Comment: I don't have errors, no logs, no reports, nothing, the product works in all the other functions like buy it normally.